# How to suppress warnings regarding naming conventions?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

For one of my enum classes I'd like to use non-standard naming:

```
enum class MyEnum {
    I_like_to_use,
    This_strange_naming_here
}
```

The IDE (and code inspection) rightfully complains with:

```
Enum entry name 'This_strange_naming_here' doesn't match regex '[A-Z]([A-Za-z\d]*|[A-Z_\d]*)'.
This inspection reports enum entry named that do not follow the recommended naming conventions.
```

However in this case, I would like to actively suppress this warning. I tried with `@Suppress("naming")`, but to no avail.

Comment: "Enum entry naming convention" popup window suggests to use `@Suppress("EnumEntryName")` instead of `@Suppress("naming")`

Comment: @awesoon Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @TobiasHermann, you can accept answer by CrazyCoder, it is the same as mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [Suppress inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html). You are not supposed to type it by hand.

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to invoke the pop-up menu for the light bulb, select the inspection or the suggested quick fix from the drop-down menu, press the **right arrow** on the keyboard to open the sub-menu on the right, choose the Suppress option.

[image: Suppress]

Comment: This dialog is by far not offered for all issues the inspection complains about, esp. not for naming issues it seems.

Comment: @sschuberth could you please provide the example/sample code/project where it's not available?

Comment: Sure @CrazyCoder, see e.g. https://github.com/sschuberth/stan/blob/8be8d24faf4a67e474577efcd6614c29069d7893/cli/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt#L42, where the IDE inspection complains about unused code. You can suppress that only manually via `@Suppress("unused")`. Similarly, if you rename one of the sealed class members to `WITH_UNDERSCORE` you get the hint "Class name 'WITH_UNDERSCORE' should not contain underscores", but no way to automatically suppress it, and I'm actually having a hard time figuring out the name of the hint to suppress.

Comment: @sschuberth Please check these screenshots: https://i.imgur.com/b5yR85L.png, https://i.imgur.com/ZEbohj4.png. Suppressing works as described in my answer and in the linked IDE documentation section. For the second case it adds `@Suppress("ClassName")`.

Comment: You're right, thanks. It's just very unobvious to me how to trigger this menu. Just hovering over the identifier will only show a tooltip with "Safe delete" and "More actions", but not the yellow bulb. You actually have to first put the cursor onto the identifier to make the bulb show up, and then you must not click on the "Safe delete" text, but on the arrow next to it to get to the "Suppress" sub-menu.

Comment: @sschuberth documentation and the screenshot in my answer have the precise instructions how to invoke this menu. Sorry if it was not clear and "thanks" for downvoting the correct answer.

Comment: No reason to get snippy. As you probably know, I cannot undo my downvote until you edit your answer. Which is a good idea anyway, as you should [not hide relevant information behind links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: That is exactly why the screenshot of the relevant documentation section was included in the answer, so that you can read it without following the (possibly dead) links. So your statement about hiding the relevant information behind the links doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 11):

For Kotlin/Java add

```
@Suppress("LocalVariableName", "PropertyName")
```

above the class name to suppress naming conventions warnings for global and local variables.

Answer (score 8):

`@Suppress("EnumEntryName")` use these